# Is there an equivalent source command in Windows CMD as in bash or tcsh?

Tags: windows, bash, unix, cmd, tcsh

I know that in the unix world, if you edit your `.profile` or `.cshrc` file, you can do a `source ~/.profile` or `source ~/.cshrc` to get the effect on your current session.  If I changed something in the system variable on Windows, how can I have it effect the current command prompt session without exiting the command prompt session and opening another command prompt session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid not, but you can start using Powershell, which does support dot sourcing. Since powershell window is really based on cmd so all your dos command will continue to work, and you gain new power, much more power.

Comment: Thanks John Shen.  I have search the web and haven't found any equivalent.  I have seen Powershell, perhaps I will start using that instead of the old command prompt.

Comment: Couldn't get powershell to do this

Comment: TLDR: Power! *Unlimited* power!

Comment: "call" worked for me, as the second answer with more than 10 upvotes proves, too.

Answer (score 66):

In the usual Windows command prompt (i.e. cmd.exe), just using `call mybat.bat` did what I wanted. I got all the environment variables it had set.

Comment: If mybat.bat runs other batch scripts, it needs to `call` them to allow execution to return to the current script.

Comment: `call` won't work for powershell scripts however. Suppose you want to import a function and invoke it, `source` would work in bash

Comment: This is a very old question, but I think this should be the correct answer.

"call myfile.bat"   --> reads the environment variables from the batch file and sets those in current environment from where "call" command is invoked. then all those variables are available for use in the current shell.

Comment: Oh, and it was at a perfect 42... I almost wish I hadn't upvoted and just left it there. Thanks much! :)

Answer (score 18):

The dos shell will support .bat files containing just assignments to variables that, when executed, will create the variables in the current environment.

```
  c:> type EnvSetTest.bat
  set TESTXYZ=XYZ

  c:> .\EnvSetTest.bat

  c:> set | find "TESTX"
  TESTXYZ=XYZ
  c:>
```

IHTH.

Comment: @thomasa88: you can click the down vote button again to remove the down vote

Comment: @BeniBela You can only undo the vote for a few minutes, then it gets locked.

shellter: Vote corrected, thanks for the good answer :)

Also found that setlocal can be used for local variables, and one can move data between local and global like this: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/In_a_DOS_batch_file_how_do_you_copy_a_local_variable_to_a_global_variable

Answer (score 9):

Following example will help you to solve your problem.

`env.bat` This file is for setting variables. Its contents are given blow.

```
set name="test3"
```

`test.bat`  Our main batch file.

```
call env.bat
call print.bat
pause
```

Now `print.bat` batch file to print variables. Its contents given below

```
echo %name%
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have found this to work is to launch a new cmd window from my own config window. eg:

```
@echo off
echo Loading...
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
call 1.cmd
call 2.bat
...
...
if "%LocalAppData%"=="" set LocalAppData=%UserProfile%\Local Settings\Application Data
SET BLAHNAME=FILE:%LocalAppData%\BLAH
call blah blah
cmd
```

The last cmd will launch a new cmd prompt with the desired settings exported to the command window.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a *workaround* for some limited use-cases.  You can read-in a file of commands and execute them in-line.  For example the calling command file looks like:

```
echo   OFF
SETLOCAL  ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
     :
echo.         ----------------
echo.           set-up java
echo.         ----------------
echo.
rem       call    %DEV_SCRIPTS%\setup-java
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ( %DEV_SCRIPTS%\setup-java.bat ) do (
    %%A
)        
call    %DEV_SCRIPTS%\show-java
     :
```

In the `setup-java.bat` file you can't use `%` expansion.  You need to use `!`; e.g.:

```
    set  JRE_HOME=!JRE_08!
    rem        
    set  JRE_TARGET=!JRE_HOME!
```

So you are litterally `source`-ing commands from a text file.  You will need to test which commands *sourced* in this way.  It took a few trials just to set some environment variables.

I don't think we can do logic or loops because the command processor scans the file at the start.  I am OK just having a simple workaround to reuse shared things like environment definitions.  Most other things won't need an actual `source` command (*I am hoping*).  Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

For example to set VC# vars

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
```

Answer (score -8):

Use git bash for windows, it works totally fine!