# Is there an equivalent of the bash source command in Windows CMD?

Tags: windows, cmd

I tried the command `call`, but it runs another instance of the CMD shell attached to a new console. Is there a way to execute the commands from the other file in the current CMD shell?

Comment: Are you **really** using MS-DOS or are you talking about the Windows command line (which is something very different)

Comment: The tags "windows" and "dos" seem appropriate to your question, but how is it related to "bash"?

Comment: @Abra: the command line in Windows has **nothing** to do with "DOS" or "MS-DOS"

Comment: `call` will **not** start a new cmd window

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I was being a bit lenient. I believe one could easily assume Windows and DOS are related, but knowing why bash is also included may help understand the question asked, which I think you'll agree, is not completely clear.

Comment: @Abra: Windows and "DOS" have not been "related" since Windows 2000

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name a quick Internet search gives me the impression that many people still refer to the command prompt as the DOS prompt, so even though they are not related, people use both terms to refer to the former. Hence my request for clarification.

Comment: I believe this a duplicate question and was answered here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402379/is-there-an-equivalent-source-command-in-dos-command-prompt-as-in-bash-or-tcsh

Comment: I edited out two common mistakes. The CMD shell is a Windows console application, not a DOS application. (DOS used a similar but simpler shell named COMMAND.COM.) It is also a source of confusion to call it a "cmd window". The window is a console -- an OS provided resource that CMD allocates or inherits by default; however, it can run without one.

Comment: If you're going to use the `bash` tag, that implies that people who are experts in bash can be expected to answer your question. That's not the case here, so that tag shouldn't be present.

Comment: Also, please provide a concrete example. In general, from the command line you can 'source' another batch script by simply running it. In a batch script itself, use `call` to allow returning to the current script. Neither of these starts a new instance of CMD unless you're explicitly using `cmd /c` or `start`. Since you say a new console is created, you're probably using `start`, either directly in the current script or indirectly in the other script.