# Multiple python installation - how keep them separate?

Tags: python

I was working on the project that I had to use Python version 2.7.11 dues to a strict customer requirement.  I just became a part of another project that I have to use Python 2.7.16, again strict customer requirement.

I originally installed my 2.7.11 in C:\Python27\ on my Windows machine.  With understanding that installing multiple version of Python is possible, I installed 2.7.16 in C:\Python2.7.16\ on the same machine.  I selected an option not to add this new python installation to PATH.

When I opened the command window and typed python.exe, python returned below output.

```
C:\>python
Python 2.7.16 (v2.7.16:413a49145e, Mar  4 2019, 01:30:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Thinking somehow the PATH got added, I checked the PATH variable, but it does not show the new path.

I tried to find out what is really running, but it was the installation of my old python, 2.7.11.

```
C:\>python
Python 2.7.16 (v2.7.16:413a49145e, Mar  4 2019, 01:30:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Python27\\python.exe'
>>>
```

I also tried to run my old python specifically, but the result was the same.

```
C:\>C:\Python27\python.exe
Python 2.7.16 (v2.7.16:413a49145e, Mar  4 2019, 01:30:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

If I run the new installation, it looks like it correctly runs the 7.2.16 as below.

```
C:\>C:\Python2.7.16\python.exe
Python 2.7.16 (v2.7.16:413a49145e, Mar  4 2019, 01:30:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Python2.7.16\\python.exe'
>>>
```

What is happening here?  What version of Python am I running when I run the command "**C:\Python27\python.exe**"?

Did I change the version of Python installed in "C:\Python27\"?  If not, why does the execution of python display the wrong version?

Comment: You should read about `docker`

Comment: virtualenv? conda?

Comment: @ozlevka, Yes, I use the virtual environment.  I have several virtual environments for my 2.7.11 installation.  I am actually very worried about the contamination of the virtual environment also.  I was checking the health of the installation  of both 2.7.11 and 2.7.16 before I create a venv for newly installed 2.7.16.  I am very concerned now......

Comment: You can delete virtuaenv any time. You can use some analog to source command on Windows https://stackoverflow.com/a/50792493/1573395. And docker, as @Uri Goren suggest, it will be a good solution.

Comment: @ozlevka, what do you think it is happening?  When I run python 2.7.11, why does it display 2.7.16?  I checked the file dates, I know files did not get overwritten.

Comment: Consider learning how to use `pipenv` It will help you manage your projects in a sane way.