# Can't connect .env file of smtp details to django

Tags: django, smtp

1. settings.py

> ```
> EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
> EMAIL_HOST = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST')
> EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
> EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
>
> EMAIL_PORT = 587
> EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
> ```

2. .env

> ```
> export EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=<>
> export EMAIL_HOST_USER = <>
> export EMAIL_HOST=<>
> ```

3.Termial

> ```
> (Carealenv) E:\atom data\mywebsite>source .env
> 'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> ```

I am having error of SMTPserverdisconnected .. please run connect first
I want to connect my .env file to django so that SMTPServer get connected and i can send verfication email to users. It will be great help.. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to ruddra's answer, you can alternatively use [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/).

`pip install python-dotenv`

then in your settings.py

```py
# settings.py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
```

Then you can use the `getenv` or as you have in your example `environ.get` function from the built-in `os` module to grab env variables and provide defaults if they do not exist.

```py
from os import getenv

EMAIL_HOST = getenv('EMAIL_HOST', 'localhost')
```

Where localhost is whatever you wish to set as default.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `source` in Windows machine as described in the [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402379/is-there-an-equivalent-source-command-in-windows-cmd-as-in-bash-or-tcsh) answer.

If you want to use .env file, consider using libraries like [`django-environ`](https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ) which will read the file directly, no need to load it from `ENVIRONMENT` Variables.

Sample usage in `settings.py`:

```
import environ
env = environ.Env(
    # set casting, default value
    DEBUG=(bool, False)
)
# reading .env file
environ.Env.read_env()

# False if not in os.environ
EMAIL_HOST = env('EMAIL_HOST')
```

Another alternative solution is to use Docker with `docker-compose`, where you can load the [environment variables from file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/).