# Redirect default port to specific port in linux/unix

Tags: linux, unix, web, port, default

I have an web application running on port 3000. f anybody wants to access, they need to access through http://thisdomain.com:3000/. I want to make the application accessible at http://thisdomain.com/.

I want to redirect default port to specific port (3000) which my application is running

How Can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change your web server settings, where you define that the domain is running on port 3000 - default http port is 80 (in this case, no need to add :80 to the url).

another option is that your web server on default port :80 returns a HTTP REDIRECT that points to :3000

Comment: In my case, This is an angular application running on NodeJs. How & where i can make changes ?

Comment: to change port from 3000 to 80, see e.g. here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181253/changing-node-js-listening-port

(use listen(80);  to listen on port 80)

Comment: Currently my application is listen to 3000, i do not want change and i have code api.listen (3000). Issues is not with changing port #.                                             if anybody wants to access, they need to access through http://thisdomain.com:3000/. I want to make the application accessible at http://thisdomain.com/.

Comment: does anybody have answer for this ?