# How to redirect to a vuejs front-end running on port 8080 from Nodejs backend on port 3000 along with data

Tags: node.js, vue.js, redirect, vue-cli

I can redirect using

```
res.writeHead(302, {
    Location: 'http://localhost:8080/path'
})
```

But I need to send some data along with redirection. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to pass data from redirecting is to put it as a query param, for example

```js
res.writeHead(302, {
    Location: 'http://localhost:8080/path?data=1'
})
```

and on your vue app, you can get the query param with:

```
this.$route.query.data
```

Keep in mind that this is not secure and not recommended if you are passing a sensitive data.

**EDIT:**

You can also pass the data as path params if it fits your need, for example you have your vue route like this:

```js
routes: [
    {
      path: '/path/:data',
      name: 'path',
      component: PathPage,
    },
]
```

you can redirect from your express app like this:

```js
res.writeHead(302, {
    Location: 'http://localhost:8080/path/50'
})
```

and you can get the parameter from your vue component like this:

```js
this.$route.params.data // 50
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `listen()` method is what you need for nodejs backend server.

```js
var http = require('http'); 
var url = require('url'); 

http.createServer(function (req, res) { 
 console.log("Request: " + req.method + " to " + req.url); 
 res.writeHead(200, "OK"); 
 res.write("<h1>Hello</h1>Node.js is listening new port"); 
 res.end(); 
}).listen(3000);
```

Thread: [Changing Node.js listening port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181253/changing-node-js-listening-port)