# Syntax for Heroku environment variables in config.yaml for node.js?

Tags: node.js, heroku, yaml, mlab

I've tried using:

```
db:
  uri: process.env.MONGOLAB_URI
```

but that doesn't seem to be working. (EDIT: in fact, that just returns the string of "process.env.MONGOLAB_URI") I've also tried:

```
<%= ENV['MONGOLAB_URI'] %>
```

but I saw that in article for an article about yaml in a ruby app (can't find the link now).

What's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

`db:
  uri: #{process.env.MONGOLAB_URI}`

credits: https://github.com/vngrs/konfig

Answer (score -1):

I believe the config.yaml example is for a specific Ruby driver. For Node.js you want to feed the URI (found at `process.env.MONGOLAB_URI`) into the Node driver of your choice using whatever configuration method you find most convenient.

If you wanted to use the [Node MongoDB Native driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) for example you might do something like this:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
mongodb.Db.connect(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI, function (err, db) {
    // Do something cool with the db
});
```

Comment: Right, and that works when placing `process.env.MONGOLAB_URI` in the node.js code, but what syntax should be used to put it in the `config.yaml`?

Comment: If you're referring to the YAML file configuration technique documented in the [MongoLab add-on help](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab), then as I mentioned that's for a particular Ruby driver and doesn't apply to Node.js. Is the problem that you're looking to externalize the configuration from the code and perhaps fork on the environment being used?

Comment: I guess I'm not being clear. I understand that one of the syntaxes I used in the question is for ruby and not for node.js, that's why I said that in the question. I also understand that I can access the mongolab_uri environmental variable in javascript code by using `process.env.MONGOLAB_URI` in the node.js code. The problem is that when using a yaml file for app config, you can't use `process.env.MONGOLAB_UI` by itself, because yaml will just return that string and not evaluate the string as javascript code. What's the syntax to tell yaml that it should evaluate the string as javscript?

Comment: I believe that depends on the YAML parser you're using. Are you using [js-yaml](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml)? I don't see an obvious solution from a quick review of the README.md or a visit to their [online demo](http://nodeca.github.com/js-yaml/). Taking a step back, though, YAML isn't the usual way to handle configuration in Node. You may want to try one of the [techniques more commonly used with Node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869216/how-to-store-node-js-deployment-settings-configuration-files). I use [nconf](https://github.com/flatiron/nconf) myself.

Comment: nconf looks really sweet. The way it automatically processes and incorporates environmental variables might solve my issue. I'll check it out. Thanks! And sorry for the confusion