# How to create global variables accessible in all views using Express / Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, template-engine, ejs

Ok, so I have built a blog using [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) and you can define variables in a file `_config.yml` which are accessible in all of the templates/layouts. I am currently using [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org) / [Express](http://expressjs.com) with [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/) templates and [ejs-locals](https://github.com/RandomEtc/ejs-locals) (for partials/layouts. I am looking to do something similar to the global variables like `site.title` that are found in `_config.yml` if anyone is familiar with Jekyll.  I have variables like the site's title, (rather than page title), author/company name, which stay the same on all of my pages.

Here is an example of what I am currently doing.:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    res.render('index', { 
        siteTitle: 'My Website Title',
        pageTitle: 'The Root Splash Page',
        author: 'Cory Gross',
        description: 'My app description',
        indexSpecificData: someData
    });
};

exports.home = function (req, res) {
    res.render('home', {
        siteTitle: 'My Website Title',
        pageTitle: 'The Home Page',
        author: 'Cory Gross',
        description: 'My app description',
        homeSpecificData: someOtherData
    });
};
```

I would like to be able to define variables like my site's title, description, author, etc in one place and have them accessible in my layouts/templates through EJS without having to pass them as options to each call to `res.render`. Is there a way to do this and still allow me to pass in other variables specific to each page?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

## Update for Express Versions 4/5+:

The best solution for handling this is still by using [app.locals](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.locals) as documented in the Express API Reference. As some of the comments here note, the API was updated in Express 4 such that `app.locals` is no longer a function, but is now simply an object. So if you try to call it as a function you will get an error.

To use app.locals in Express 4/5+ to accomplish the same thing as in my original example for Express 3 below, you could set `app.locals` like so anywhere in your application where you have access to the Express `app` object:

```js
app.locals = {
    site: {
        title: 'ExpressBootstrapEJS',
        description: 'A boilerplate for a simple web application with a Node.JS and Express backend, with an EJS template with using Twitter Bootstrap.'
    },
    author: {
        name: 'Cory Gross',
        contact: 'coryg89@gmail.com'
    }
};
```

This would make all of these values globally available within all views accessible as `site.title`, `site.description`, `author.name`, and `author.contact` respectively.

##### **NOTE:** Alternatively, you can also set values on `app.locals` separately.

For example, this would also work:

```js
app.locals.authorName = 'Cory Gross';
app.locals.authorContact = 'coryg89@gmail.com';
```

However, by default, this would ***not*** work, and would throw an error:

```js
app.locals.author.name = 'Cory Gross';
app.locals.author.contact = 'coryg89@gmail.com';
```

This happens because, while `app.locals` already exists as an object exposed by Express which you can define properties on, `app.locals.author` does not yet exist and so the above will throw an error complaining that you trying to set a property on an object that is undefined. In order to do the above you would first have to set `app.locals.author = {}` as an empty object or just set everything under `app.locals` or `app.locals.author` at the same time, similar to my first example above.

### Usage in Middleware

Although, the values set on `app.locals` are made globally accessible in all views, one of the potential issues with using it in Express 3 was that those values were not necessarily accessible within middleware functions by default. Because of this limitation, one alternative, as originally suggested in [Pickel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16463328/1359785), was setting the values on `res.locals` in a top level middleware instead so that the values would be available in all lower middleware as well as in all views. However, this alternative came with the downside that the logic for setting all of these values would be executed over and over again for every single request/response rather than being set one time and persisting as long as the server is running as is the case with `app.locals`.

In Express 4/5+, there is now a better solution if you want the values that you're setting on `app.locals` to be available within middleware functions as well as in all views. To solve this issue, the Express 4/5+ API now exposes the Express `app` object within all middleware functions, accessible as a property on the `req` parameter as `req.app`. So, by default, you can now easily access all of the global application scoped values set on `app.locals` within all middleware functions as well simply by accessing the object as `req.app.locals` within your middleware.

## Original Answer for Express Version 3:

After having a chance to study the [Express 3 API Reference](https://expressjs.com/en/3x/api.html) a bit more I discovered what I was looking for. Specifically the entries for [app.locals](https://expressjs.com/en/3x/api.html#app.locals) and then a bit farther down [res.locals](https://expressjs.com/en/3x/api.html#res.locals) held the answers I needed.

I discovered for myself that the function `app.locals` takes an object and stores all of its properties as global variables scoped to the application. These globals are passed as local variables to each view. The function `res.locals`, however, is scoped to the request and thus, response local variables are accessible only to the view(s) rendered during that particular request/response.

So for my case in my `app.js` what I did was add:

```js
app.locals({
    site: {
        title: 'ExpressBootstrapEJS',
        description: 'A boilerplate for a simple web application with a Node.JS and Express backend, with an EJS template with using Twitter Bootstrap.'
    },
    author: {
        name: 'Cory Gross',
        contact: 'coryg89@gmail.com'
    }
});
```

Then all of these variables are accessible in my views as `site.title`, `site.description`, `author.name`, `author.contact`.

I could also define local variables for each response to a request with `res.locals`, or simply pass variables like the page's title in as the `options`parameter in the `render` call.

**EDIT:** This method will *not* allow you to use these locals in your middleware. I actually did run into this as Pickels suggests in the comment below. In this case you will need to create a middleware function as such in his alternative (and appreciated) answer. Your middleware function will need to add them to `res.locals` for each response and then call `next`. This middleware function will need to be placed above any other middleware which needs to use these locals.

**EDIT:** Another difference between declaring locals via `app.locals` and `res.locals` is that with `app.locals` the variables are set a single time and persist throughout the life of the application. When you set locals with `res.locals` in your middleware, these are set everytime you get a request. You should basically prefer setting globals via `app.locals` unless the value depends on the request `req` variable passed into the middleware. If the value doesn't change then it will be more efficient for it to be set just once in `app.locals`.

Comment: app.locals makes more sense than what I suggested. It has one catch though, you can't access the locals in your middleware. In this case it probably doesn't matter but it's one of those gotchas that you sometimes run into.

Comment: You can also define configuration in a js or json file and simply require() it everywhere you need it. The file will only load once during the application, and every module that requires it gets access to the values it defined. See the various answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869216/how-to-store-node-js-deployment-settings-configuration-files

Comment: In **Express 4** `locals` is not a function, but an object. To set a property: `app.locals.site.title = 'Example';`

Comment: Wow! Now whole app is configurable through a single file. A clean shot. +1

Comment: @MarttiLaine Thanks buddy!

Comment: Local variables are available in middleware on the request object in 4x via [req.app.locals](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.locals)

Comment: @MarttiLaine I can only seem to set one level down... so `app.locals.title = 'Example'` works but `app.locals.site.title = 'Example'` does not. Why is that?

Comment: @volumeone same here on express 4.17.1

Comment: On Express 4 simply assign a object to app.locals like `app.locals = { site: { title: 'Example' } }`

Comment: @volumeone @RemoHarsono This is because `app.locals` itself is already pre-defined by Express as an object which you can set properties on, and so directly setting `app.locals.title` works as expected—However, by default `app.locals.site` will be undefined initially, and so trying to directly set `app.locals.site.title` without first explicitly defining `app.locals.site` itself will throw an error complaining that you're trying to set a property on something that is undefined. See my updated answer above for more info.

Answer (score 60):

You can do this by adding them to the locals object in a general middleware.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   res.locals = {
     siteTitle: "My Website's Title",
     pageTitle: "The Home Page",
     author: "Cory Gross",
     description: "My app's description",
   };
   next();
});
```

Locals is also a function which will extend the locals object rather than overwriting it. So the following works as well

```
res.locals({
  siteTitle: "My Website's Title",
  pageTitle: "The Home Page",
  author: "Cory Gross",
  description: "My app's description",
});
```

**Full example**

```
var app = express();

var middleware = {

    render: function (view) {
        return function (req, res, next) {
            res.render(view);
        }
    },

    globalLocals: function (req, res, next) {
        res.locals({ 
            siteTitle: "My Website's Title",
            pageTitle: "The Root Splash Page",
            author: "Cory Gross",
            description: "My app's description",
        });
        next();
    },

    index: function (req, res, next) {
        res.locals({
            indexSpecificData: someData
        });
        next();
    }

};


app.use(middleware.globalLocals);
app.get('/', middleware.index, middleware.render('home'));
app.get('/products', middleware.products, middleware.render('products'));
```

I also added a generic render middleware. This way you don't have to add res.render to each route which means you have better code reuse. Once you go down the reusable middleware route you'll notice you will have lots of building blocks which will speed up development tremendously.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but the params in your `globalLocals` function for `req` and `res` are backwards.

Comment: Can I query data intended to be global, this way, e.g. navbar data that loads directly from db each page request?  That seems to be this idea might be overstepping the usage of locals, e.g. a mongoose call. I am looking for direct load, on every route, since navbar is global, will look into caching later.  Alternatively, maybe i need a function that runs once, then loads these to locals after collecting the data.

Comment: `res.locals` doesn't seem to be a function anymore.

Comment: I use your approach to show some products into the footer. Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

For Express 4.0 I found that using application level variables works a little differently & Cory's answer did not work for me.

From the docs: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals

I found that you could declare a global variable for the app in

```
app.locals
```

e.g

```
app.locals.baseUrl = "http://www.google.com"
```

And then in your application you can access these variables & in your express middleware you can access them in the req object as

```
req.app.locals.baseUrl
```

e.g.

```
console.log(req.app.locals.baseUrl)
//prints out http://www.google.com
```

Comment: Also the express server needs to be restarted when new locals are added in code.

Answer (score 17):

In your app.js you need add something like this

```
global.myvar = 100;
```

Now, in all your files you want use this variable, you can just access it as `myvar`

Comment: I'm using require modules, and had to reference it as `global.myvar` everywhere, and that worked.  This was a nice easy solution for socket.io, where I want to emit messages from handlers in other files.    I put my "io" object on `global.myIO` and all is working great.

Comment: This is actually not recommended or considered a good practice in Node development. Node.JS includes a module system implementation based on the CommonJS system and is completely centered on the idea of modules which do not share a global scope, instead using the require method. This also sets a global js var in Node instead of a local for Express view/templates like the question asks for.

Comment: @CoryGross Is it a good practice to set request object as a global variable like this?

Comment: Only this worked. Thanks Mr. F! @CoryGross how do I let all files in my application access a single object?

Comment: This is the best answer. It means the global object is available to pass to a view or anywhere you want. Like `global.cdnURL = "https://cdn.domain.com` that you can pass to a view to load up static conent.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this by updating the `app.locals` variable for that app in `app.js`

Set via following

```
var app = express();
app.locals.appName = "DRC on FHIR";
```

Get / Access

```
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('[' + app.locals.appName + '] => app listening on port 3001!');
});
```

Elaborating with a screenshot from @RamRovi example with slight enhancement.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can also use "global"

Example:

declare like this :

```
  app.use(function(req,res,next){
      global.site_url = req.headers.host;   // hostname = 'localhost:8080'
      next();
   });
```

Use like this:
  in any views or ejs file
     <% 
         console.log(site_url);
      %>

in js files
     console.log(site_url);

Comment: This will cause race conditions. global isn't namespaced to that particular request.

Answer (score 0):

With the differents answers, I implemented this code to use an external file JSON loaded in "app.locals"

**Parameters**

```
{
    "web": {
        "title" : "Le titre de ma Page",
        "cssFile" : "20200608_1018.css"
    }
}
```

**Application**

```
var express     = require('express');
var appli       = express();
var serveur     = require('http').Server(appli);

var myParams    = require('./include/my_params.json');
var myFonctions = require('./include/my_fonctions.js');

appli.locals = myParams;
```

**EJS Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><%= web.title %></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/<%= web.cssFile %>">
</head>

</body>
</html>
```

Hoping it will help

Answer (score -1):

What I do in order to avoid having a polluted global scope is to create a script that I can include anywhere.

```
// my-script.js
const ActionsOverTime = require('@bigteam/node-aot').ActionsOverTime;
const config = require('../../config/config').actionsOverTime;
let aotInstance;

(function () {
  if (!aotInstance) {
    console.log('Create new aot instance');
    aotInstance = ActionsOverTime.createActionOverTimeEmitter(config);
  }
})();

exports = aotInstance;
```

Doing this will only create a new instance once and share that everywhere where the file is included. I am not sure if it is because the variable is cached or of it because of an internal reference mechanism for the application (that might include caching). Any comments on how node resolves this would be great.

Maybe also read this to get the gist on how require works:
http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/