# Setting global variables for swig with nodejs or express render

Tags: node.js, express, global, swig-template

I am putting a bootstrap framework together for myself in node using express and swig as the tpl engine.

I am used to working with frameworks such as ezpublish where ini settings can be pulled from the tpl code. I don't actually like this way.

However there will always be content that the required in multiple places eg:

```
//general site details
module.exports = {
    'siteName' : 'my site',
    'emails' : {
        'noReply' : 'no-reply@mysite.com',
        'accouts' : 'accounts@mysite.com',
        'support' : 'support@mysite.com'
    },
    'website': 'www.mysite.com',
    'googleAnalytics': {
        'trackingID': 'UA-123321213-1'
    }
};
```

I would like to be able to always have the above information available to any swig template the app uses. Is there a way to define these as globals so i don't have to pass them through on every single route?

Doing this in each route seems crazy:

```
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        res.render('private/profile.html', {
            user : req.user,
            siteDetails: siteDetails /* this should be automatic */
        });
    });
```

If it is not possible to set gloabls with the swig tpl engine, is it possible to set an object to always be passed through to the express render functionality?

Thanks
John

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452123/how-to-create-global-variables-accessible-in-all-views-using-express-node-js

I found an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
app.locals.siteDetails = require('./config/site');
```

Then once in the template, you can access the object via:

```
{{siteDetails.googleAnalytics.trackingID}}
```