# Creating Middleware Global vs local var

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

During my research on how to better handle globally used data I found this Question  [See 2. Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452123/how-to-create-global-variables-accessible-in-all-views-using-express-node-js)

So I integrated this approach into my code basis and came up with a problem, which i would like to discuss. Hope someone can help me here.

I created a new file `middleware.js`containing almost the same code as in the answer from SO, just with some small modifications:

```
const url = require('../db/url');

module.exports = {
           render: function (view) {
            return function (req, res, next) {
                res.render(view);
            }
        },

        globalLocals: function (req, res, next) {
          res.locals = { 
                title: "My Website's Title",
                pageTitle: "The Root Splash Page",
                author: "Cory Gross",
                description: "My app's description",
            };
            next();
        },

        index: async function (req, res, next) {
            res.locals = {
                index: "index2",
                loggedIn: req.user ? true : false,
                linkObj: await url.getAllUrl()
            };
            next();
        }
};
```

In my app.js I included the file and simply told my app to use the globalLocals:

```
var middleware = require('./config/middleware');
app.use(middleware.globalLocals);
```

Afterwards without any other changes I integrated this into my `ejs template` and it worked:

`<h1><%= title %></h1>`

Great!

After this was done I played a bit with the `index`part of my middleware and also integrated this one via in my `app.js` but in a different way, because I just want to make this "index" variables available for my index router for a clear seperation!!

`app.use("/", middleware.index, indexRouter);`

So now I was able to access the values defined in the middleware and use them in ejs. BUT I was no longer be able to access any of my `globalLocals` and I don´t understand WHY?

Can someone tell me how I can keep the seperation as descibed above and access both objects in my ejs template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do this

```
res.locals = {
                // properties
            };
```

you're overriding previous values of locals from previous middlewares calls (because you're creating a completely new object). You need to extend `res.locals` with the new values, not create a completely new object. To do so, use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) which will copy the new values (second parameter) into the object with the old values (first parameter) - keep in mind that if they are named the same, you will be overriding them!

```
globalLocals: function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals = Object.assign(res.locals, { 
        title: "My Website's Title",
        pageTitle: "The Root Splash Page",
        author: "Cory Gross",
        description: "My app's description",
    });
    next();
},

index: async function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals = Object.assign(res.locals, {
        index: "index2",
        loggedIn: req.user ? true : false,
        linkObj: await url.getAllUrl()
    });
    next();
}
```

Comment: This totally makes sense, don´t know how i missed that. Thanks a lot, it worked!