# How does one provide global properties to the render engine

Tags: nestjs, server-side-rendering

How does one provide global properties to the [template renderer](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mvc#template-rendering) in order to not explicitly define it in every rendering endpoint?

e.g. the url the request is calling for.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16502225/6336460) and works perfectly by injecting with a middleware and specifying what routes with the [middleware consumer](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware#applying-middleware).

> note that with express 4.x locals is an object and not a function.