# Having hierarchical node.js config files

Tags: node.js, config

I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869216/how-to-store-node-js-deployment-settings-configuration-files) first before I come here.
My question is a little different than that.
I have following folder structure.

- app.js
- **global.config.js**
- node-modules

  - my module

    - **module.config.js**
    - **index.js**

global.config.js:

```
var config = {};
config.loggingLevel: "error"; // global setting for all custom modules
```

module.config.js:

```
var config = {};
config.loggingLevel: "info"; // ideally should override global setting
```

index.js

```
var globalDir = path.dirname(require.main.filename) + "\\global.config.js";
var globalConfig = require(globalDir);
var moduleConfig = require("./module.config.js");
// merge configs here and use only one config object
```

As seen here, I have a global and module specific config files. I would like to merge them into one config file and use that way.

Is there any way to achieve this easily? (Like a pre-written module) Or should I iterate through each property and override if same key exists?

Comment: please check this for merge objects http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Comment: @KrzysztofSztompka this fixed my issue for now. If not exists, I will be thinking writing a module for this or add functionality to existing one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a module located under https://github.com/quimsy/espresso which contains a Config Tree Builder. Its (partly) a port of Symfony's Config Component.

You can define a configuration tree:

```
var TreeBuilder = require("Espresso/Config/Definition/Builder/TreeBuilder");
var builder = new TreeBuilder();
var root = builder.root("connection");

root
    .children()
        .scalarNode("host").defaultValue("localhost").end()
    .end();
```

And with a Processor You can merge multiple configurations respecting these rules:

```
var Processor = require("Espresso/Config/Definition/Processor");
var processor = new Processor();
var mergedConfiguration = processor.process( root.getNode(), [ config1, config2 ] );
```

Regarding the example above, You would do something like:

```
var builder = new (require("Espresso/Config/Definition/Builder/TreeBuilder")();
var root = builder.root("myConfigRoot");
/* some definitions */

var processor = new (require("Espresso/Config/Definition/Processor"))();
var config = processor.process( root.getNode(), [ globalConfig, moduleConfig ] );
```

Look at [Defining and Processing Configuration Values](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html), since this module is 90% compatible - some different naming conventions and taking respect to Array/Objects (in PHP there is only the Array type).

Comment: Please be patient. I just started using git. Let me know, if there are some issues. Im so excited :D

Comment: is this supporting json configuration? Looks like it is made for working with YAML and XML.

Comment: Config/Definition only deals with defining/processing configuration objects. You can just require a .json file and process it as described above. Loading is handled by Config/Loader Subclasses. I havent implement them, because I'm also satisfied with `require("some.json")`

Comment: It would be great have this as separate module. Anyway I will pull out dependencies and give it a try. Since I am not using espresso framework, I do not want to pull out extra dependencies which I will not need.