# .gitignore doesn't work when pulling

Tags: git, github

I have file named `config.xml`. I added .gitignore and within it I put config.xml. I do `git rm --cached config.xml` and commit my changes. In the future my changes on config.xml in my local won't effect anything. But that's not what I want.

I want 2 version of config.xml. On my remote branch I will use production code and in my local I want to have localhost configuration. How to do that? I'm lost..

Comment: Try to not put config into version control.. It's bad for many scenario.

Comment: That's not how you do this. Git is designed to synchronise across multiple locations, not have different versions in different places.

Comment: @weigreen I use git to deploy stuff, if not where else I should put it? it's a part of the application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 1):

## with git

you can use a `post-merge` [git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to replace the content of the `config.xml` file with the content of your local file that you can rename `config.local.xml`

## without git

you can have two configs files : `config.dev.xml` and `config.prod.xml`. The way to use the right files at the right place depend on the framework you use.

Comment: I use node.js with express. How can I know it's on localhost or in server? I don't think it's possible because it's an API.

Comment: you can have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8563528/700317), linking to [nconf](https://github.com/indexzero/nconf). Also, sometimes, it's good to "lose" some time to read the documentation ;)