# How to structure configs with NodeJS and express?

Tags: node.js, express

Apologies for the basic question but im very new to NodeJS and Express

I want to have separate properties (such as db connection strings or encryption keys etc) for my local, test and production environments

I was wondering what is the best way to do this?
If anyone can point to a tutorial or any best practices it would be much appreciated

Thanks
Damien

Comment: have  look at this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/config

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store Node.js deployment settings/configuration files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869216/how-to-store-node-js-deployment-settings-configuration-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both dotenv and the config package will do the trick but I think I will go with the config package

Cheers
Damien

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) which is an npm package to do exactly what you need.